# Dotfuscator Error while trying to build a .Net Core console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I have a simple .Net Core console app and am trying to obfuscate the generated dll using `Dotfuscator Community` tool https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/index.html:

```
 class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nFunction to calculate the sum of two numbers :\n");
            Console.Write("--------------------------------------------------\n");
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter another number: ");
            int n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe sum of two numbers is : {0} \n", Sum(n1, n2));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static int Sum(int num1, int num2)
        {
            int total;
            total = num1 + num2;
            return total;
        }
    }
```

After choosing the generated dll from the `Add Input` option, when I try to build it using the `Build` option, I get `Build Error`(screenshot below) although the program builds successfully in my local.

[image]

Apparently, from the error, it seemed that System.Runtime inside the `bin -> Debug -> netcoreapp3.1` folder is missing; so I installed it in my application, but the error still persists.

[image]

My .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Obfuscar" Version="2.2.28">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Have you tried following the [documentation](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html#integrate-core)?

Comment: I work for the Dotfuscator team. The documentation Youssef13 linked is for the Professional Edition; there's no MSBuild integration for Community Edition except when building Xamarin apps. I think you had the Community Edition set up correctly at first, though maybe including another obfuscator (Obfuscar) as a package is causing issues? Also, are you using the latest Community Edition? You can download free updates [from our website](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads).

Comment: @JoeSewell ookay, understood. Yes, I noticed that I did have another obfuscator installed(Obfuscar). What I did now is, I created a new console app(without installing any other Obfuscator) and tried to build it from the tool, but, again got the same build error(same as the first screenshot). FYI I'm using Dotfuscator Community Version: 5.42.0.9514-e0e25f754. Where am I going wrong now?

Comment: You should update to the latest version, 5.44.0, which is available at the link I posted, click the button in the Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019 row.

Comment: @JoeSewell hey, upgrading to v5.44 worked, thanks! But when I tried to check the contents of the generated dll in the newly generated Dotfuscated folder through the 'ILSpy' tool, I can see no changes in the content. The build succeeded this time, then, why is it like this?

Comment: By default, the renaming obfuscation won't rename things that are referencable from outside of the assembly (i.e. `public`, `protected`, or `protected internal`), in case some other (unobfuscated) code was referencing the assembly you're protecting. Since this is a console app, you can disable [Library Mode](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_inputs.html#library-mode) on the Inputs screen for more renaming. You can also add `internal` types and `internal` or `private` methods to your code, and Dotfuscator will rename them even when Library Mode is on.

Comment: @JoeSewell Yes it worked now, thanks!